# JQuery UI Resizable - Don't resize properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using the jquery ui resizable. 
jquery: 1.10.2
jquery ui: 1.10.3
ui css: 1.10.3 (smoothness).

I have applied "resizable" and "draggable" on same object within constrain resize/drag area. It works perfect if the container is the first div on the page. But suppose I have added 2 divs above it for title of the page and other ui elements, it does not resize properly. In this case, the resize event stops before the constrain area. The difference is exactly equal to the height of the 2 divs I have added above the constrain area.

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that illustrates the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gauravgr/899q9/6/
Try to resize it to bottom.